# Вытащить из HTML блок с помощью PHP

Tags: php, html, синтаксический-анализ

Есть страница с блоком (например, `<div id="info">Информация</div>`).
Как с помощью PHP вытащить этот блок?

Comment: @n130, Уточните свой вопрос.

Comment: Можете вытащить весь код сайта( PHP: file_get_contents() ) и потом уже на своем сайте распарсить полученный код яваскриптом или jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Библиотеки для парсинга html средствами PHP.

[Simple HTML Dom parser](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/)

[phpQuery](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Хотя если у вас одна небольшая задача, то стоит поискать пути попроще, а не использовать большие библиотеки для одной задачи.

UPD. Погуглив, [нашел топик на stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355452/using-a-regular-expression-to-match-a-div-block-having-a-specific-id). Там предложили рабочее выражение, как и следовало ожидать - весьма сложное. Приведу его без комментариев (тыкните на ссылку, там все разжевано).

```
<div\b[^>]*?\bid\s*+=\s*+([\'"]?+)\bcontent\b(?(1)\1)[^>]*+>((?:[^<]++(?:<(?!/?div\b|!--)[^<]*+)*+|<!--.*?-->|<div\b[^>]*+>(?2)</div\s*>)*+)</div\s*>
```

Выражение корректно грабит div#content со всеми внутренностями. (Опять же, в оригинальном топике описываются исключительные случаи).

Вообщем, если структура нужного блока известна, то можно использовать решение @Barton, если нет - проще использовать библиотеку, код будет понятнее)

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```
$href = 'http://site.name';
$page = file_get_contents($href);
preg_match("/<div.*id=\"info\".*>(.*)<\/div>/",$page,$match);
print_r($match);
```

Comment: <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="info">inner text</div>
    </div>
Мне кажется или ваш код вытащит блок вместе с закрывающим тегом родителя?

Comment: @gridsane только что проверил, вытаскивает то что надо.

`$page = '<div class="wrapper"><div id="info">Some text</div></div>';
preg_match("/<div.*id=\"info\".*>(.*)<\/div>/",$page,$match);
print_r($match);`

Comment: Это если по умолчанию нежадный поиск в (.*). А если в #info будут вложенные div?

По-моему еще . исключает переносы строки.

Comment: в данном случае речи о каких либо внутренних блоках не было. Когда ТС спросит, тогда будем решать проблему

Comment: Так же как и не было речи про то что их нет) Удачи вам, с такими решениями проблем)

Comment: Раз мой вариант не полный, вы бы предложили свой

Comment: Если с использованием регулярных выражений, то простыми способами я пока не могу придумать как это сделать) Пытался из вас вытянуть)

Comment: strip_tags($str) - почистит содержимое <div id="info"></div> от тегов. Останется только текст. Пусть автор даст пример, что есть внутри div

Comment: Классический комментарий о том, что парсить HTML регулярками - ВСЕГДА плохая идея: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1688077

Answer (score 0):

```
$page = 'http://google.com';
$pos = strpos($page, '<div class="Нужен этот блок">');
$page = substr($page, $pos);
$pos = strpos($page, '<div class="Этот блок стоит сл, после того что нужен, его и все что после нужно также удалить">');
$page = substr($page, 0, $pos);
```

Если нужно получить только внутренности, то используя данный код + немного js, будет непонятно как именно, могу разжевать.

Answer (score -1):

Есть много способов , вот [статья](http://www.parsing-and-i.blogspot.com/2009/08/html-php.html), очень занимательна